# Control the dots separation in math and text

Tags: spacing, kerning, mathtools, ellipsis

I know how to control the spacing of the `\textellipsis` command. But I can't figure it out how to do so globally in all the versions of `mathtools`' `\*dots`.

My idea is to use a global symbol `…` to use `\dots` (in math mode) or `\textellipsis` (in text mode).

### How can I change the default spacing in ALL dots commands?

I want smaller separation between them (but the same in all of them). Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{…}{\dots}

\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
    .\kern.35\fontdimen3\font
    .\kern.35\fontdimen3\font
    .\kern.35\fontdimen3\font}

\begin{document}
…a...a{\textellipsis}a…a$…=…=a\times…\times a$
\end{document}
```

By the way, shouldn't the definition of `\textellipsis` look more like this?

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
    .\kern.35\fontdimen3\font
    .\kern.35\fontdimen3\font
    .}%\kern.35\fontdimen3\font}
```

### Update

After posting here I started to see `ellipsis` package everywhere (until now I “never hear of it” but now it's everywhere :P). Which redefines the `\textellipsis` in a more convenient way (and takes in account something similar to my last definition of `\textellipsis`). But, still, doesn't solve the problem with math `\dots`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In math mode three different varieties of dots are used:

1. `\dotsb@`, defined as

   ```
   \mathinner{\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp}
   ```

   for centered dots;
2. `\@cdots`, defined in the same way, but it's a different macro, for dots between integral signs;
3. `\@ldots`, that expands to the kernel's `\mathellipsis`, that is

   ```
   \mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp\ldotp}
   ```

If you want to change the spacing, you have to redefine all three macros.

For instance, you might want to add some negative kerning:

```
\renewcommand{\dotsb@}{%
  \mathinner{\cdotp\mkern-1mu\cdotp\mkern-1mu\cdotp}%
}
```

Why is there a kern also after the final period in `\textellipsis`? It's the American usage.

Comment: Great. By the way, instead of `\cdotp\mkern-1mu` I think `{\cdotp}\kern.35\fontdimen3\font` would be better to be “coherent”. *American usage*, well if I don't want that, then there is no problem with redefining all those commands `\dotsb@`, `\@cdots`, `\@ldots`, and `\textellipsis` without the last kern? Or is there something I should be aware of?

Comment: @Manuel You're right, the last kern is not needed. However, `\mathinner` adds a thin space on both sides in display and text style.