# How to make \dots from amsmath and ellipsis work together

Tags: amsmath, ellipsis

The `amsmath` package changes the `\dots` command to have different vertical alignment depending on context (I'm not sure if it does anything else to it). The `ellipsis` package changes the `\dots` command to ensure correct spacing in certain textual contexts. However, it seems to undo the changes made by `amsmath`. Is there a way to make the features work simultaneously?

The following is an mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ellipsis}

\begin{document}

a \dots{} b

a\dots{}b
\[a + \dots + b\]

\end{document}
```

If the ellipsis package is used, the ellipsis in math is not vertically centered. If it is not used, there is an extra (thin?) space after the ellipsis in the text. The order of `\usepackage`'s do not seem to matter.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `\dots{}` in math mode anyway, because it confuses the macros of `amsmath`.

Comment: I can't see any difference in the vertical alignment of `\dots` with and without `amsmath`.

Comment: Inside of math you shouldn't use the `{}` after `\dots`, you must let them decide the spacing `a + \dots + b`. By the way, this may interest you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168383/21930 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179336/21930.

Comment: @egreg -- huh?  shouldn't use `\dots` in math?  or were you just referring to the `{}` *after* `\dots`?  the `amsmath` documentation specifically recommends using `\dots` unless a final reading shows that some of them have gotten misaligned.  (the `{}` is almost always wrong though.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I wasn't clear: `{}` shouldn't be used after `\dots` in math mode.

Comment: The `{}` after `\dots` in math mode was accidental when typing out the mwe. Since in this case it doesn't affect the output (at least noticably) and hence the question, I edited it out.

Comment: @ronno It does, in fact, affect quite much. `a + \dots{} + b` does not give you vertically shifted dots, which is what, at first time, you asked for.

Comment: @Manuel Ah, you're right, of course. Then the edit was needed to make the mwe work consistently with the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ellipsis` package does

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \DeclareRobustCommand{\dots}{%
     \ifmmode\mathellipsis\else\expandafter\textellipsis\fi}%
}
```

which is wrong, because it reinstates the LaTeX kernel definition without taking into account that other package might have redefined it. The package author's aim is ensuring that in text mode the redefined `\textellipsis` is used. Alas, this breaks the `amsmath` mechanism.

Solution: reinstate the correct definition given by `amsmath` that *has* `\textellipsis` for text mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{letltxmacro} % for saving and reinstating the correct macro
\usepackage{amsmath}
% save the definition of \dots by amsmath
\LetLtxMacro{\amsmathdots}{\dots}

\usepackage{ellipsis}

% this must go after \usepackage{ellipsis}
\AtBeginDocument{\LetLtxMacro{\dots}{\amsmathdots}}

\begin{document}

a \dots{} b

a\dots{}b
\[a + \dots + b\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I used some time ago. It adds `\ellipsisbeforegap` and `\ellipsisaftergap` just because I needed it. You can delete it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ellipsis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mathellipsis}{%
    \mathinner{%
        \kern\ellipsisbeforegap%
        {\ldotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
        {\ldotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
        {\ldotp}\kern\ellipsisaftergap%
    }%
}
\renewcommand*{\dotsb@}{%
    \mathinner{%
        \kern\ellipsisbeforegap%
        {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
        {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
        {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisaftergap%
    }%
}
\renewcommand*{\@cdots}{%
    \mathinner{%
        \kern\ellipsisbeforegap%
        {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
        {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
        {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisaftergap%
    }%
}
\renewcommand*{\ellipsis@default}{%
    \ellipsis@before
    \kern\ellipsisbeforegap
    .\kern\ellipsisgap
    .\kern\ellipsisgap
    .\kern\ellipsisgap
    \ellipsis@after\relax}
\renewcommand*{\ellipsis@centered}{%
    \ellipsis@before
    \kern\ellipsisbeforegap
    .\kern\ellipsisgap
    .\kern\ellipsisgap
    .\kern\ellipsisaftergap
    \ellipsis@after\relax}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\dots}{%
        \ifmmode\@xp\mdots@\else\@xp\textellipsis\fi}}
\def\ellipsisgap{.1em}
\def\ellipsisbeforegap{.05em}
\def\ellipsisaftergap{.05em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a \dots\ b

a\dots b

\[ a + \dots + b \]

\end{document}
```

The relevant part to your question (although my code is more complete) is

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\dots}{%
        \ifmmode\@xp\mdots@\else\@xp\textellipsis\fi}}
```

[image]