# How do I make \dots more compact? Or are there alternatives?

Tags: macros

How would I go about making `\dots` more compact? I prefer the dots to be closer together to save horizontal space in long equations.

Alternatively, is there another inherently more compact macro than `\dots`? Would be preferable as regular `\dots` could still be used in other contexts.

Comment: Have you seen the `ellipsis` package?

Comment: Do you need this in math-mode, too? `\usepackage{ellipsis}
\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{0.1em}` just works in text-mode. And it will redefine your normal `\dots`-command. Even `\let\olddots\dots` does not work then.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188679/21930) does add to the usual options of `ellipsis` package, two more configurable spaces: `\ellipsisbeforegap` and `\ellipsisaftergap` (space before and after the dots, useful in many cases), apart from making it configurable also for math mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mydots{\hbox to 1em{.\hss.\hss.}}
\begin{document}

Hello\dots

Hello again\mydots

\end{document}
```

Or if you prefer to keep it all "clean" LaTeX commands:

```
\newcommand\mydots{\makebox[1em][c]{.\hfil.\hfil.}}
```

A further consideration would be whether you care about maths mode or not.  The standard `\dots` command carefully checks whether we are in maths or not and does the right thing.   If you want to worry about this, then you would need this:

```
\newcommand\mydots{\ifmmode\ldots\else\makebox[1em][c]{.\hfil.\hfil.}\fi}
```

[image]

In order to change the spacing of the dots with this solution, you change the overall width of the ellipsis.  In the above examples I've made it `1em` wide, and the the `\hss` or the `\hfil` commands expand as needed to make the dots evenly spaced.

If your ellipsis is ever followed by more text, then there is another consideration: whether you want any built-in space after the ellipsis (as pointed out in the comments).  The original `\dots` command has a small amount of space after it, but my suggested replacement above does not.  For example

[image]

To fix this you can either add a thin space after it by hand or amend the definition to:

```
\newcommand\mydots{\ifmmode\ldots\else\makebox[1em][c]{.\hfil.\hfil.}\thinspace\fi}
```

Comment: you might add some text following the dots.  the appearance of the dots in relation to what follows is also important.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, useful consideration.

Comment: This works really well in text mode. As I was specifically looking for a more compact version of `\dots` in math mode (which I failed to mention in the question) I went with your  "clean LaTeX commands"-implementation of `\mydots` and tweaked it a little. Now, it reads `\newcommand\varlist{,\makebox[1em][c]{.\hfil.\hfil.},}
`. This in the context of say `$\Psi_0(\vec{r}_1\varlist\vec{r}_n)$` produces much more desirable output than `$\Psi_0(\vec{r}_1,\dots,\vec{r}_n)$`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is another option: expanding `ellipsis` package to work also in math mode, apart from adding two more dimensions (`\ellipsisbeforegap` and `\ellipsisaftergap`, if set to zero it has the same behaviour as in `ellipsis` package).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ellipsis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mathellipsis}{%
  \mathinner{%
    \kern\ellipsisbeforegap%
    {\ldotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
    {\ldotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
    {\ldotp}\kern\ellipsisaftergap%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\dotsb@}{%
  \mathinner{%
    \kern\ellipsisbeforegap%
    {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
    {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
    {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisaftergap%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\@cdots}{%
  \mathinner{%
    \kern\ellipsisbeforegap%
    {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
    {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisgap%
    {\cdotp}\kern\ellipsisaftergap%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\ellipsis@default}{%
  \ellipsis@before
  \kern\ellipsisbeforegap
  .\kern\ellipsisgap
  .\kern\ellipsisgap
  .\kern\ellipsisgap
  \ellipsis@after\relax}
\renewcommand*{\ellipsis@centered}{%
  \ellipsis@before
  \kern\ellipsisbeforegap
  .\kern\ellipsisgap
  .\kern\ellipsisgap
  .\kern\ellipsisaftergap
  \ellipsis@after\relax}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\dots}{%
    \ifmmode\@xp\mdots@\else\@xp\textellipsis\fi}}
\def\ellipsisgap{.1em}
\def\ellipsisbeforegap{.05em}
\def\ellipsisaftergap{.05em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a \dots\ b

a\dots b

\[ a + \dots + b \]

\end{document}
```

Also, [this question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179336/configurable-spacing-after-dots) might be interesting in case you want to configure the spacing after the dots for diferent glyphs (e.g., `!`, `?`, `,`, `;`, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Or with kerning:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myDots}{\ifmmode\mathellipsis\else.\kern-0.13em.\kern-0.13em.\fi} % touching at \kern-0.1725em

\begin{document}
\myDots

\dots 

$\myDots$

$\dots$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have different kerning for the math-version, you can just replace `\mathellipsis` by something else.

**Update**: for full control over math- and text-mode, you can use the following command: `\newcommand{\myDots}{\ifmmode\mathinner{\ldotp\kern-0.2em\ldotp\kern-0.2em\ldotp}\else.\kern-0.13em.\kern-0.13em.\fi}`

---

A second possibility (just for text-mode) would be the package `ellipsis`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ellipsis} 
\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{0.01em}

\begin{document}
\dots $\dots$
\end{document}
```